# React native - which files to include in version control after installing native-base?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, gitignore

I started react-native project, and decided to test [native-base](http://nativebase.io/) library. Installing it and its dependencies resulted in changes to both ios and android folders. **I'm not sure should I put these changes to version control or not?**

The changes were:

**ios:**

ios/AppName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: I see hashes with fonts added

ios/AppName/Info.plist: Fonts are added here too inside  tags

**android:**

android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/[20 different fonts]

So apparently, installing react-native native-base resulted in getting some fonts to the native folders? The best practise standard .gitignore files for react-native projects does not ignore these files, hence my version control client is showing the files to me. But I wonder if all of those changes were made only because of installing some third party libraries, then should I put them to version control? As the peer coders will also install those, and they should get the same files, right?

What I worry is that some important files in the native directory will become unsynced between the developers of this project. If they install the native-base, and it results in change for some core files in ios side, then that change might not be exactly the same (for example, there might have been minor version update etc.). I don't really know what to do, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a [very similar issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/931) has came up for others too.

One possible solution is to check, whether it's a compatibility issue and [downgrade React Native](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/931#issuecomment-309766336) for start.

The other [potential solution](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/931#issuecomment-309924675) might be is to **reinstall React Native with NPM**:

```
npm install react-native --save
```

If this doesn't help, **try again, but** before installing React Native with NPM, remove `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` directory *(on Linux)*:

```
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
```

If you use Yarn, try to use NPM instead and see whether this resolves your problem.